# rdbms "view" equivalent on orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is there a "view" equivalent on orientdb?

I have a rdbms background and am looking for a way to save a query as an object which i can query directly.

Take for example the following query

`SELECT mobile_number                            AS mobile_number, 
       verifications.verification_code[0]       AS verification_code, 
       verifications.is_verified[0]             AS is_verified, 
       Max(verifications.active_devices .@ rid) AS device_rid, 
       verifications.active_devices .@ version  AS active_version 
FROM   guests`

I would like to create a "view" with this query called `verified_guests`, then I would like to execute a query against `verified_guests` using something like `select from verified_guests`

In the rdbms world, I would be able to do the following

`create view verified_guests as 
SELECT mobile_number                            AS mobile_number, 
       verifications.verification_code[0]       AS verification_code, 
       verifications.is_verified[0]             AS is_verified, 
       Max(verifications.active_devices .@ rid) AS device_rid, 
       verifications.active_devices .@ version  AS active_version 
FROM   guests`

then I would be able to `select * from verified_guests`.

Does orientdb have an equivalent or an alternative to this?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I made this schema to reproduce your issue:

```
create class guests extends V
create property guests.mobile_number integer
create property guests.name string
```

[image]

try this:

```
create class verified_guests extends V
INSERT INTO verified_guests FROM SELECT mobile_number, name FROM guests
```

this is the result:

```
select * from verified_guests
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: In RDBMS a view is just a query.  If you add/delete/update records in any of the underlying tables and the view automatically reflects those changes.  That is not happening in this example.  I tried this in OrientDB and verified_guests does not automatically pull in additions to guests.  What you have shown is not at all like a view in a SQL database.  Or am I missing something?